# Configuring multiple inline sinks to dataflows within a pipeline dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to configure inline sinks for my dataflows which are connected to snowflake stage tables. How can I cycle through these tables within a pipeline so each dataflow is connected to 1 of n inline sink?

I've configured them manually but is there a more dynamic way of doing this, such as through a function call?

Answer (score 0):

To configure multiple inline datasets dynamically, you can use dataflow parameters.

For, snowflake inline dataset, the Sink settings will be like this.

[image]

So, create dataflow parameters of string type for both schema and table and pass the values for these from pipeline to dataflow activity.

For sample, I am doing it for SQL inline sink which has similar Sink settings as snowflake.

Create two dataflow parameters and give those in `Schema name` and `Table name` of Sink settings.

[image]

[image]

In pipeline, I had an array of table names `["mycsv2","Sample1_1"]` and I have given it to a ForEach activity. Inside ForEach, I took dataflow activity and passing the table name and schema name in each iteration.

[image]

Now, execute this pipeline and you can see that my pipeline created the required tables in the target.

[image]